# How to assign weight to a layout for image view?

Tags: image, android-layout, android-layout-weight

Please help me, i want to create following type of layout with buttons on the top of image view.
[image]
My code is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_area"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_edit"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/edit_profile_bg"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@mipmap/edit_profile_bg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:src="@mipmap/edit_profile_bg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/lin_edit"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/edit_profile_bg"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@mipmap/edit_profile_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@mipmap/edit_profile_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

how can i add buttons ? and also the images are not aligned properly via weight. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Below one is layout you wanted, **button with imageview**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_edit_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="Button 1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />
        </LinearLayout >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="Button 2" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="Button 3" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />
        </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="Button 4" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />
        </LinearLayout >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="Button 5" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />
        </LinearLayout >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:hint="Button 6" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/cal" />
        </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout >
```

you can also use

> **library** https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView
>
> Android ListView that mimics a GridView with asymmetric items.
>   Supports items with row span and column span

[image]

[image]